# How to prevent div section to move below?

Tags: css

I have а search page and want to prevent "top20" div section on the right to move below the section rounded by rectangle when I change the size of browser window.

CSS:

```
#search_parameters_border {
    border: 1px outset gray;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;    
}

#searchBox {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#categories {
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 420px;
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;        
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#additionalFilters {
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;       
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#top20 {
    width: 650px;
    padding: 5px;        
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

The screen shot:

[image]

Comment: you need to make the screen have a min-width of 1370px (or put them in a container with that width)

Comment: Do you mean on whole search screen?

Comment: #top20 { position:absolute; left: 0px;} ?

Comment: yes - if you want the two containers to stay side bby side then the screen (body) or containing div must be at least the width of both of them plus any side margin and side padding - so actually it needs to be at least 1400px as I forgot to add padding before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using absolute values for all widths you need to give a min-width to the surrounding container. Than you're top20 div will not move. 
But you should consider making you're style more fluid.

Comment: What do you mean "more fluid"?

Comment: Use percent for you width, or try em, which i prefer.

Comment: For example. This is not as absolute as pixel

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have a containing element for your floats, the phone is allowing your last float to get pushed down below where you're not wanting it to go. It's generally a good idea to use a "container" or "wrapper" div as you'll see them referenced to at times with your site's maximum allowed width to surround your builds (or min-width if you want to get a little fancier.) It will solve your issue as well as help you stay organized. As well, like in this situation, if you run into problems, sometimes it can be faster to just set a property in your "container" div to "position:relative;" and then position the div you're having trouble with absolutely via "position:absolute; top:100px; left:50px;" or something similar for spacing. If you have any questions about anything above or in the other comments let me know and I can explain in more detail.